# RDP requesting password

Tags: vb.net, rdp, mstsc

I'm working on a RDP application, but windows is ignoring my password provided in the code and is showing the prompt for password input, here is my code:

```
rdp.Server = server
rdp.UserName = user
rdp.TransportSettings3.GatewayHostname = gateway
rdp.TransportSettings3.GatewayUsageMethod = 1
rdp.TransportSettings3.GatewayCredsSource = 4
rdp.TransportSettings3.GatewayProfileUsageMethod = 1
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.AuthenticationLevel = 0
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.EnableAutoReconnect = True
rdp.AdvancedSettings9.DisplayConnectionBar = True

Dim IRCNS As MSTSCLib.IMsRdpClientNonScriptable5 =
DirectCast(rdp.GetOcx(), IMsTscNonScriptable)

IRCNS.PromptForCredentials = False
IRCNS.AllowPromptingForCredentials = False
IRCNS.ClearTextPassword = pwd
IRCNS.PromptForCredsOnClient = False

rdpView.Connect()
```

Comment: When using a username/password the role on the server must allow the credentials.  See : https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS752US753&ei=lB21X9LPIMir5wKT-7CQDQ&q=msdn+http+roles&oq=msdn+http+roles&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQRzoICAAQCBAHEB46CAgAEA0QChAeOggIABAIEA0QHlC0O1juQGD6S2gAcAJ4AIABhAGIAaoEkgEDMC41mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCLgBA8ABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjS6e7UlYztAhXI1VkKHZM9DNIQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: Can you explain me this? I don't get it.

OBS: I'm connecting to an AWS computer, provided by my company's software provider

Comment: A lot of corporate networks do not allow authentication from an untrusted machine.  So login using username/password is not allowed.

Comment: When I connect using username/password in mstsc, works fine, when I connect using my app, works fine too, but is requesting the password, the username the app still recognizes and show as "pattern" on connection prompt. If I type the same password, it connects

Comment: The remote desktop is the issue.  You are making a new connection to the remote machine.  See : https://superuser.com/questions/321866/how-to-prevent-remote-desktop-login-when-user-is-logged-in-locally

Comment: Thank you, I read the link and is exactly this the problem. I avoided it with a "macro" to user/password.